# Prevent two threads entering a code block with the same value

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Say I have this function (assume I'm accessing Cache in a threadsafe way):

```
object GetCachedValue(string id)
{
    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(id))
    {
         //long running operation to fetch the value for id
         object value = GetTheValueForId(id);
         Cache.Add(id, value);
    }     
    return Cache[id];
}
```

I want to prevent two threads from running the "*long running operation*" at the same time **for the same value**. Obviously I can wrap the whole thing in a lock(), but then the whole function would block regardless of value and I want two threads to be able to perform the long running operation as long as they're looking for different id's.

Is there a built-in locking mechanism to lock based on a value so one thread can block while the other thread completes the *long running operation* so I don't need to do it twice (or N times)? Ideally as long as the *long running operation* is being performed in one thread, no other thread should be able to do it for the same id value.

I could roll my own by putting the id's in a HashSet and then removing them once the operation completes, but that seems like a hack.

Comment: You could do a lock on String.Intern(id). But then you should be damn sure, that your "id" String is very (!) unique in your app ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783092.aspx) here. Below code will lock the cache, put the `Lazy` into the cache and return immediately. *Long-running-operation* will be executed once in a thread safe manner.

```
new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("1-" + GetCachedValue("1").Value)).Start();
new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("2-" + GetCachedValue("1").Value)).Start();
```

---

```
Lazy<object> GetCachedValue(string id)
{
    lock (Cache)
    {
        if (!Cache.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            Lazy<object> lazy = new Lazy<object>(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("**Long Running Job**");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    return int.Parse(id);
                }, 
                true);

            Cache.Add(id, lazy);
            Console.WriteLine("added to cache");
        }
        return Cache[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Race condition: Reading from the cache concurrently with writing.

Comment: @Usr I can easily move `return Cache[id];` into the `lock` block without hurting any performance, but there is no race condition. `return Cache[id];` is guaranteed to return a `Lazy<object>`

Comment: Sure, just wanted people not to copy the code literally and have strange runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would like to have interface like this

```
using (SyncDispatcher.Enter(id))
{
    //any code here...
}
```

so I could execute any code and it would be thread safe if id is the same.
If I need to get value from Cache I get it straight forward, as just there is no concurrency calls.

My implementation for SyncDispatcher is this:

```
public class SyncDispatcher : IDisposable
{
    private static object _lock = new object();
    private static Dictionary<object, SyncDispatcher> _container = new Dictionary<object, SyncDispatcher>();

    private AutoResetEvent _syncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    private SyncDispatcher() { }

    private void Lock()
    {
        _syncEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _syncEvent.Set();
    }

    public static SyncDispatcher Enter(object obj)
    {
        var objDispatcher = GetSyncDispatcher(obj);
        objDispatcher.Lock();

        return objDispatcher;
    }

    private static SyncDispatcher GetSyncDispatcher(object obj)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_container.ContainsKey(obj))
            {
                _container.Add(obj, new SyncDispatcher());
            }

            return _container[obj];
        }
    }
}
```

Simple test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(() => Execute("1", 1000, "Resource 1")).Start();
    new Thread(() => Execute("2", 200, "Resource 2")).Start();
    new Thread(() => Execute("1", 0, "Resource 1 again")).Start();  
}

static void Execute(object id, int timeout, string message)
{
    using (SyncDispatcher.Enter(id))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);

        Console.WriteLine(message);              
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your locking down to where your comment is. I think you need to maintain a list of currently-executing *long running operations*, and lock accesses to that list, and only execute the `GetValueForId` if the `id` you're looking for isn't in that list. I'll try and whip something up.

```
private List<string> m_runningCacheIds = new List<string>();

object GetCachedValue(string id)
{
    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(id))
    {
         lock (m_runningCacheIds) {
             if (m_runningCacheIds.Contains(id)) {
                 // Do something to wait until the other Get is done....
             }
             else {
                 m_runningCacheIds.Add(id);
             }
         }

         //long running operation to fetch the value for id

         object value = GetTheValueForId(id);
         Cache.Add(id, value);

         lock (m_runningCacheIds)
             m_runningCacheIds.Remove(id);
    }     
    return Cache[id];
}
```

There's still the issue of what the thread is going to do while it waits on the other thread is getting the value.

Comment: That will cause a deadlock. After the first is done fetching, it will try to lock m_runningCacheIds, which is currently locked by the second as it waits for the first to finish.

Comment: @CodeNaked - Right, I wasn't meaning for the thread to actually wait at that point in the code. I just hadn't figured out yet how to make it wait on the cache result.

Answer (score 0):

I use in that cases the [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) as:

```
object GetCachedValue(string Key)
{
    // note here that I use the key as the name of the mutex
    // also here you need to check that the key have no invalid charater
    //   to used as mutex name.
    var mut = new Mutex(true, key);

    try
    {   
        // Wait until it is safe to enter.
        mut.WaitOne();

        // here you create your cache
        if (!Cache.ContainsKey(Key))
        {
             //long running operation to fetch the value for id
             object value = GetTheValueForId(Key);
             Cache.Add(Key, value);
        }     

        return Cache[Key];        
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the Mutex.
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }   
}
```

Notes:

- Some characters are not valid for the mutex name (like the slash)
- If the Cache is different for every application (or web pool) that you use, and it is if we speak for the cache of asp.net, then the mutex is lock all threads and pools in the computer, in this case I also use a static random integer that I add it to the key, and not make the lock different for each key but also for each pool.

Answer (score -2):

It's not the most elegant solution in the world, but I've gotten around this issue with a double check and a lock:

```
object GetCachedValue(string id)
{
    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(id))
    {
         lock (_staticObj)
         {
            if (!Cache.ContainsKey(id))
            {
               //long running operation to fetch the value for id
               object value = GetTheValueForId(id);
               Cache.Add(id, value);
            }
         }
    }     
    return Cache[id];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this locks `GetTheValueForId` for *all* identifiers.  I think that the OP wants multiple concurrent executions possible for different identifiers.

Comment: -1: This helps once the long-running operation is complete and the new value is stored, but locks until then.