# Request throttling with asynchronous waiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, throttling

I have implemented some request throttling in my app. Its based around using the MemoryCache and expiring items according to a limit. Basically i try to retrieve a cache item, if its not there I go ahead and make the request, if it is their I check the last request and workout the next available time I can make the request. My problem lies when i have to wait to make a request.

```
//This is a shortened version of what im doing, but the includes the required code

public void ThrottleRequest(string webservice)
{
    if (cache.TryGet(webservice))
    {
          var timeToWait = GetTimeToWaitFromSomewhere(); 
          Wait(timeToWait);
    }
}

public async void Wait(TimeSpan timeToWait)
{
     await Task.Delay(timeToWait); //This doesnt work
     Thread.Sleep(timeToWait); //This works
}
```

The issues are in the wait method. If i use thread.sleep numbers match up and the requests are throttled correctly (ie 1 request per second) but i would never want to use this in a production environment though. So whats the correct way to wait asychronously here? Am i misusing the API or something?

Comment: You should avoid `async void`. I give all the reasons in my [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: This may also help [Prevent two threads entering a code block with the same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073147/prevent-two-threads-entering-a-code-block-with-the-same-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `Wait` method has a return type of `void` - you're basically saying, "Start waiting, and I'll keep going, ignoring the wait!"

You'd normally have it as:

```
public async Task ThrottleRequest(string webservice)
{
    if (cache.TryGet(webservice))
    {
        var timeToWait = GetTimeToWaitFromSomewhere(); 
        await Wait(timeToWait);
    }
}

public async Task Wait(TimeSpan timeToWait)
{
     await Task.Delay(timeToWait);
}
```

Although at that point, your `Wait` method is pointless, and you'd be better to write:

```
public async Task ThrottleRequest(string webservice)
{
    if (cache.TryGet(webservice))
    {
        var timeToWait = GetTimeToWaitFromSomewhere(); 
        await Task.Delay(timeToWait);
    }
}
```

Note that I've changed your `ThrottleRequest` method to be async and to return `Task` as well. It's not clear what you were hoping that calling `Wait` would achieve on its own, but if you're trying to introduce asynchrony, you need to be very clear about what you're doing - and usually the method which *calls* an async method will *also* be asynchronous.

If you *really* just wanted to pause the currently executing thread in `ThrottleRequest`, then you shouldn't be using an async method at all - you'd want to *synchronously* delay, which is precisely what `Thread.Sleep` does.

I strongly suspect you don't have a totally clear idea of what your code is meant to be doing in terms of being synchronous or asynchronous at the moment. I would take a step back from the code itself and work out how you actually expect it to work (think about what you want the threading model to be, for example), *then* go back to the keyboard.

Also consider that after the delay has occurred, you're not checking the cache again - that means if 20 different threads each get into your method at once, they'll *all* end up hitting the web service, instead of only one of them doing so and the rest using the cached result.

Comment: wow that was quick! and i see where ive gone wrong now, Thank you very  much.

Comment: i do actually check the cache afterwards in a FIFO fashion but that code has been left out. Regarding asynchronous/synchronous i guess your right i am a bit unclear about this part and need to do a bit more reading.